# Evaluating URL params, not returning expected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

My URL is as follows:

```
http://localhost:3000/movies?ratings[PG-13]=1&commit=Refresh
```

I'm experimenting evaluating URL params and am unsure why this works the way is does.  In my controller I evaluate the parameters and build an array as follows:

In my `View` I use the following debug statement to see what gets placed into `@selected_ratings`

```
=debug(@selected_ratings)
```

In my controller I have tried two statements.

Test one returns the following, this should work?

```
@selected_ratings = (params["ratings[PG-13]"].present? ? params["ratings[PG-13]"] : "notworking")

output: notworking
```

However if I use the following ternary evaluation n my controller:

```
@selected_ratings = (params["ratings"].present? ? params["ratings"] : "notworking")

output:!map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
  PG-13: "1"
```

Why will my evaluation not find the literal `params["ratings[PG-13]"]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails parses string parameters of the form `a[b]=c` as a hash [1] where `b` is a key and `c` is its associated value: `{ :a => { :b => "c" } }`.

So the url `http://localhost:3000/movies?ratings[PG-13]=1&commit=Refresh` will result in the hash:

```
{ :ratings => { :'PG-13' => "1"}, :commit => "Refresh" }
```

In your first assignment, you check if `params["ratings[PG-13]"]` is present, and since it is not, it returns "notworking". In the second case, you check if `params["ratings"]` is present, and it is, so it returns `params["ratings"]`, which is a hash with the key `PG-13` and value `"1"`.

[1] Or rather, a [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess), a special kind of hash that [converts symbol and string keys into a single type](http://syntatic.wordpress.com/2007/11/28/ruby-on-rails-merge-params-with-a-hash-indifferently/).

Comment: so I should do `params["ratings"].has_key("PG-13")`?  Tough, how to search a hash, when the value is another hash......

Comment: Can't you just test `params["ratings"]["PG-13"]`? It will return a "1" in this case, which as a boolean will be true. If the key is not present, it will return `nil`. You should probably also add a check that `params["ratings"]` is not nil.

Comment: Ahh I didnt know I could do that, `params["ratings"]["PG-13"]`.  Im brand new to rails/ruby...I will have to play with it more.  Thanks for the help.